# To specify an object while using the phrasal verb "put on"

Tags: grammar

When the object is obvious, do you usually cut it out?

Examples:

> 1. Put your glasses on (your face).
> 2. Put your shoes on (your feet).
> 3. Put your watch on (around your wrist).

Comment: Sure. Notice you already are leaving out the **subject**, "You".

Comment: If you don't omit the object, it's hardly a phrasal verb: 'John put his hat on his head / on the table.' Compare 'John wore his hat on his head' – though the prepositional phrase is non-optional with 'put'. The transitive MWV 'put on' (= don) is optionally separable: 'John put on his glasses' / 'John put his glasses on.' With pronouns, the separation is mandatory: 'John put them on.'

Answer (score 1):

Another phrase with implied information is "put on your shoes and socks". If a robot obeyed that literally the results would be comical.